# IIS7 Error 500 - Out of Ideas

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, permissions, 500-error

I'm getting a 500.19 error in IIS7 for a site I've set up locally. I've given IIS_IUSRS and even Everyone full control on the directory and reinstalled ASP.NET in IIS. I can't request any files - images etc, and I've spent so long looking for solutions and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: What is full error when you view the site on the server? (Or with remote errors disabled)

Comment: What does the eventviewer log?

Answer (score 0):

That error does not necessarily have anything to do with permissions. Have you viewed the details of the error?

Here's some info that should help: 500.19 is usually related to configuration errors.

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but there's nothing there I haven't tried.